# PHP preg_match for Placeholder [@varname]

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Sorry for dropping an other `preg_match` regular expression question. I have been dealing with this issue for too long and can't get it to work, so any help is appreciated!!

I need a simple preg_match_all to return me placeholder for the format `[@varname]`.

in a string

```
"hello, this is [@firstname], i am [@age] years old"
```

I would expect an array with the values 'firstname' and 'age'.

my attempt for `[varname]` that worked was:

```
preg_match_all("/[([^]]+)]/", $t, $result);
```

anything i tried to get the @character included failed...

```
preg_match_all("/[\@([^]]+)]/", $t, $result);
```

Comment: You should really put your attempt. A look into a regex tutorial would've taught you how to get such matches quickly.

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous to me. In the string you are parsing are you literally looking for the text '[@firstname]' or the actual results, like 'hello this is rufus' and you want to capture 'rufus'?

Comment: hi guys, thanks... i did try the tutorials, obviously i'm not getting something...

the string is: "hello, this is [@firstname], i am [@age] years old" 
i want to search for variables within the characters '[@' and ']'
and would expect an array with the values 'firstname' and 'age'

Comment: and my attempt for [varname] that worked was: 
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]+)\]/", $t, $result);

anything i tried to get the @character included failed...
preg_match_all("/\[\@([^\]]+)\]/", $t, $result);

Comment: @florian That's already pretty close! You just had to escape the outermost square brackets: `preg_match_all("/\[@([^]]+)\]/", $t, $result);` and the `@` on the other hand doesn't need to be escaped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code:

```
$str = 'hello, this is [@firstname], i am [@age] years old';
preg_match_all('~\[@(.+?)\]~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [@firstname]
            [1] => [@age]
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => firstname
            [1] => age
        )
)
```

Comment: thank you!! this worked out... easier than my approach!!
appreciate your help! cheers

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$string = "hello, this is [@firstname], i am [@age] years old";
$pattern = '#\[@(.*?)\]#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => firstname
    [1] => age
)
```